# Do you still lose all progress in the "Extra Game" when you restart your 3DS?

Tags: kirbys-adventure-3ds

It seems in the original NES version of Kirby's Adventure, turning off the console results in you losing all progress into the "extra" game where you play again with only 3 health (and 2 lives). On Wii Virtual Console, you could use the "save state"-ish feature to just never turn off the game. However any time the game resets would cause you to lose the "Extra Game" and forcing you to start over start all over.

Is this still the case in the 3DS version? Since there doesn't seem to be any way to "save state" like on Wii version, would I lose the "Extra Game" if I switch to another game or restart/turn-off the 3DS?

Comment: Oh wow what did I do to that title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally there were two ways to unlock the "Extra Game":

If you play the game and complete all the regular rooms in the game, at the end of the credits (when ability screen reads "Bye Bye"). press the <kbd>Start</kbd>,
and a special "Extra Game" screen will appear.

The other way of (permanently) unlocking this game requires you go back to find the hidden rooms after you finished the game (assuming you haven't gotten them already). After you have completed the last area (by jumping on the button), the "Extra Game" screen should appear under the "file name" sub-menu in the "Bonus Game" screen. You will still be unable to save your progress in this mode if you restart or turn off your console.

Beating this mode unlocks the Sound Test.

Comment: `You still can't save in this mode` so if I'm in Extra Game mode and the 3DS game is "closed" for any reason I still lose all progress, right?

Comment: Correct, if you exit the game or turn off the console you will still lose your progress.

Answer (score 0):

No, kind of. If you close the game, Home Button -> X, while in the middle of a play through it will save your game. If you tap the bottom screen while you're playing you'll get a menu that will give you one save point. You can reload to that point as many times as you'd like as long as you don't save again. This is separate from the temporary save of closing the game.